# Compiling a library for Ruby with SWIG on Mac OS X

Tags: c, ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard, swig

I tried to compile the following library and everything went smooth until the last step.

```
/* File : computation.c */
int add(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}

/* File: computation.i */
%module computation
extern int add(int x, int y);

$ swig -ruby computation.i
$ gcc -c computation.c
$ gcc -c computation_wrap.c -I/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin10
$ gcc -shared computation.o computation_wrap.o -o computation.so

Undefined symbols:
  "_rb_str_cat", referenced from:
      _Ruby_Format_TypeError in computation_wrap.o
  "_rb_exc_new3", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_ExceptionType in computation_wrap.o
  "_rb_define_class_under", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_define_class in computation_wrap.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_define_class in computation_wrap.o
[...]
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My configuration:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:  Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.6.3
BuildVersion: 10D575
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10]
$ swig -version
SWIG Version 1.3.40
Compiled with /usr/bin/g++-4.2 [i386-apple-darwin10.3.0]
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following flags for compiling the shared object:

```
$ gcc -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress computation.o computation_wrap.o -o computation.so
```

You also may need to add "-arch i386" since it looks like you're running 32-bit Ruby on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I had to change computation.so to computation.bundle but then it worked, thanks!